# Cas spécifique concernant l'usage du subjonctif ou de l'indicatif dans une phrase

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, indicatif

J'ai une question concernant l'usage du subjonctif dans la phrase suivante :

> Je voudrais maintenant aborder un thème adjacent, celui de l’influence que des types de logiciels, tel ChatGPT, (puissent ou peuvent)  avoir sur le comportement individuel des gens.

Faut-il conjuguer le verbe pouvoir au subjonctif ou à l'indicatif ?

Answer (score 3):

Le subjonctif n'est pas utilisable ici. On peut choisir l'indicatif (**peuvent avoir**), si l'influence est vraisemblable ou le conditionnel (**pourraient avoir**) si elle est hypothétique.

> Je voudrais maintenant aborder un thème *proche*, celui de l’influence que *certains* types de logiciels, *tels que* ChatGPT, **peuvent** avoir sur le comportement individuel des gens.

Comment: Agreed. Also, I'd prefer « l'influence que peuvent avoir ... » but that may be overly literary?...

Comment: @LukeSawczak It's fine too: *[...] celui de l'influence que peuvent avoir sur le comportement individuel des gens des logiciels tels que ChatGPT.*

Comment: @LukeSawczak "que peuvent avoir..." est un peu plus soutenu, mais passe très bien.